# Is there a SciPy function for computation of derivative of matrix exponential?

Tags: python, scipy

I work with Lie group *SO(3)*. I know there exists an analytical expression for tangent application

[image: eq1]

from which the derivative of matrix exponential can be simply computed as

[image: eq2]

What I would like to do is to compute *T(w)*.

The problem with simply implementing function *T* myself is that it is numerically imprecise for small norms of vector omega. I know there are exponential `scipy.linalg.expm` and logarithmic maps `scipy.linalg.logm` already in SciPy. Since this is similar I wonder if there is also the tangent map or the derivative. I noticed the `scipy.linalg.expm_frechet`, however, I didn't know how to connect it to *T*.

Answer (score 2):

This does not directly answer your question but for

> it is numerically imprecise for small norms of vector omega

you can just use Taylor series expansion for small |\omega| ie use something like

(1-cos(x))/x^2 = 1/2 - x^2/24, if |x| < eps, normal expression otherwise

for suitably small eps (say 1e-4)

and the same idea for (x-sin(x))/x^3

Comment: Yes, I agree with the observation. But then the problem is then how to set the value of *eps* where the approximation should be used. This is why I hoped someone had already done this.

Comment: indeed easier if somebody has already done it. but it is not difficult in this case -- by eyeballing the function and the approximation (for cos), I would say eps =5e-3 is the best cutoff, giving you noise-free behavior and accuracy well within 1e-11

Answer (score 1):

For numeric evaluation of the derivatives you can translate your code to use pytorch, and then autograd will do the work for you [a](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/autograd_tutorial.html).

For symbolic differentiation you can use sympy [b](https://zulko.wordpress.com/2012/04/15/symbolic-matrix-differentiation-with-sympy/)

Comment: Sorry, maybe my question was a bit unclear. I am not interested in implementing my own algorithm for the computation as I have already done it. I want to know if it is already implemented in SciPy like matrix exponential is for example. Or maybe there is a simple way to extract it from frechet derivative. Either way, thank you for your help. I was quite intrigued by PyTorch.

Comment: SciPy is not concerned about implementing differentiation for the functions it provides. Pytorch, SymPy, tensorflow for instance, are.
If you could give the code to implement the equations above it would be easier. I see you use a vector $\omega$ but only its norm is used. You did not define $\Omega(t)$, I can't see how you link $T(\omega(t))$ with $\Omega(t)$, this is why I didn't gave you an example code.

Comment: I don't need to differentiate. The equations for the derivative are already written in the original post. I am interested if the equation I provide is already implemented in SciPy. This is a relevant question because there exist different algorithms for computing this equation aside from evaluating it directly.